# Parsing file with ElementTree and BeautifulSoup: is there a way to parse the file by number of tag levels?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have [this](https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01048.xml) xml file, and I basically want to record all of the information into a dictionary.

I wrote this code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2
import glob
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#get the XML file
#response = requests.get('https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01048.xml')
#with open('output.txt', 'w') as input:
#          input.write(response.content)


#set up lists etc
set_of_files = glob.glob('output*txt')
val = lambda x: "{http://www.drugbank.ca}" + str(x)
key_list = ['drugbank-id','name','description','cas-number','unii','average-mass','monoisotopic-mass','state','indication','pharmacodynamics','mechanism-of-action','toxicity','metabolism','absorption','half-life','protein-binding','route-of-elimination','volume-of-distribution','fda-label','msds']
key_dict = {}
method1 = ['groups','synonyms','patent']
method3_inputs = [('dosages','dosage'),('salts','salt'),('products','product'),('mixtures','mixture'),('packagers','packager'),('categories','category'),('atc-codes','atc-code'),('pdb-entries','pdb-entry'),('food-interactions','food-interaction'),('drug-interactions','drug-interaction'),('properties','property'),('external-identifiers','external-identifier'),('external-links','external-link'),('reactions','reaction')]
list_to_run_thru = ['description','direct-parent','kingdom','superclass','class','subclass']
alternative_parents = []
http_add = '{http://www.drugbank.ca}'
substituents = []
ap_sub = lambda x:'{http://www.drugbank.ca}'+ x

def method2(list2_name,list3_name,list4_name):
     temp_list = []
     for i in subnode:
          if i.tag == list2_name:
               for a in i:
                    if a.tag == list3_name:
                         for u in a:
                              if u.tag == list4_name:
                                   temp_list.append(u.text)
     return temp_list

def method3(list1_name):
     list_of_tuples = []
     for i in subnode:
          if i.tag == list1_name:
               temp_list = []
               for a in i:
                    temp_list.append(a.text)
                    list_of_tuples.append(temp_list)
     return list_of_tuples

new_method3 = []
for i in method3_inputs:
     new_k = http_add + i[0]
     new_v = http_add + i[1]
     new_method3.append((new_k,new_v))

for each_file in set_of_files:
     tree = ET.parse(each_file)
     root = tree.getroot()
     for i in key_list:
          for child in root.getchildren():
               if i not in key_dict:
                    key_dict[i] = [child.find(val(i)).text.encode('utf-8')]
               else:
                    key_dict[i].append(child.find(val(i)).text.encode('utf-8'))

     for node in root:
          for subnode in node:
               if subnode.tag == '{http://www.drugbank.ca}general-references':
                    if 'pubmed-id' not in key_dict:
                         key_dict['pubmed-id'] = method2('{http://www.drugbank.ca}articles','{http://www.drugbank.ca}article','{http://www.drugbank.ca}pubmed-id')
                    else:
                         key_dict['pubmed-id'].append(method2('{http://www.drugbank.ca}articles','{http://www.drugbank.ca}article','{http://www.drugbank.ca}pubmed-id'))

               for a,b in zip(method3_inputs,new_method3):
                    if subnode.tag == b[0]:
                         if a[0] not in key_dict:
                              key_dict[a[0]] = method3(b[1])
                         else:
                              key_dict[method3_inputs].append(method3(b[1]))

               if subnode.tag == '{http://www.drugbank.ca}classification': 
                    for each_item in list_to_run_thru:
                         for i in subnode:
                               if i.tag == ap_sub(each_item):
                                   if i.tag == '{http://www.drugbank.ca}alternative-parent':
                                         alternative_parents.append(i.text)  
                                   if i.tag == '{http://www.drugbank.ca}substituent':
                                         substituents.append(i.text)  

               for i in method1:
                    if subnode.tag == '{http://www.drugbank.ca}' + i:
                         for n in subnode:
                              if i not in key_dict:
                                   key_dict[i] = [n.text]
                              elif i in key_dict:
                                   key_dict[i].append(n.text)

               if subnode.tag == '{http://www.drugbank.ca}pathways':
                    if 'pathways'not in key_dict:
                         key_dict['pathways'] = method2('{http://www.drugbank.ca}pathways','{http://www.drugbank.ca}pathway','{http://www.drugbank.ca}drug')
                    else:
                         key_dict['pathways'].append(method2('{http://www.drugbank.ca}pathways','{http://www.drugbank.ca}pathway','{http://www.drugbank.ca}drug'))


key_dict['alternative_parents'] = alternative_parents
key_dict['substituent'] = substituents


html = requests.get('https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01048').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div_targets = soup.find('div', class_='bond-list-container targets')
targets = div_targets.find_all('div', class_='bond card')

for target in targets:
    k = []
    v = []
    for property in target.find_all('dt'):
        k.append(property.get_text())
    for property in target.find_all('dd'):
        v.append(property.get_text())
    key_dict[target.find('strong').get_text()] = dict(zip(k, v))

print key_dict.keys()
```

The code runs on the XML file described fine. But there are some issues I would like to see if anyone can improve:

1. You can clearly see I had to hard-code a lot of it. For example, some of the tags are one-layer deep (e.g. drugbank-id), some are two layers deep (e.g. groups -> group), some are three layers deep (e.g. products, product,name) etc.

You can see that I've written a function for the two and three layers deep (the functions are called method3 and method2), and then I've hardcoded in lists that belong to each function.

I'm wondering can anyone show me code that is better/cleaner/more efficient than this. My idea would be that I have a list of IDs (e.g. description, products) and somehow the function understands 'this is a 3-layer tag (e.g. products -> product ->name), so then I don't have to hard code in all the 3-layer tags, all the 2-layer tags etc. something like having an if statement 'if tags are 3-layers deep...do this function....if tags are 2-layers deep....do this'.

2. Disclaimer: I know this method uses both BeautifulSoup and ET to parse, as I was stuck on a section and got help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904532/difficulty-parsing-a-section-of-xml-file-with-elementtree). Unfortunately I need to master one before I can move on, and I found the HTML version much more confusing than the XML, for now, so that's why the script parses the file from both a XML and HTML perspective.
3. Does anyone have any general comments on how this script can be made cleaner? The idea would be to take each of the 'top-level' tags (i.e. everything immediately below the 'drug type' tag) and then basically pull down all that info into dictionaries/lists/whatever, and then whenever I want to search for something, I can just search the dictionary for the 'top level' word and it has sub-data for that tag that I can read through (and the levels are organised properly, e.g. if there is only one level below the tag, just a string is fine, but if there is a lot of tags below the tag, maybe returning a dictionary/list/tuple/something more appropriate).

Edit:
Based on the below help, I downloaded drugbank.xsd and ran this command:

```
pyxbgen -m DB01048 -u drugbank.xsd --no-validate-changes
```

and then this script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import DB01048

xml = open('DB01048.xml').read()
d_01048 = DB01048.CreateFromDocument(xml)

#print(d_01048.drug[0].state)
#print(d_01048.drug[0].name)
#print(d_01048.drug[0].general_references.articles.article[0].pubmed_id)
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_drug_db.py", line 5, in <module>
    d_01048 = DB01048.CreateFromDocument(xml)
  File "/home/drugs/DB01048.py", line 65, in CreateFromDocument
    saxer.parse(io.BytesIO(xmld))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 213, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 365, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/home/aoidoh/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxb/binding/saxer.py", line 388, in endElementNS
    binding_object = this_state.endBindingElement()
  File "/home/aoidoh/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxb/binding/saxer.py", line 245, in endBindingElement
    return self.__bindingInstance._postDOMValidate()
  File "/home/aoidoh/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxb/binding/basis.py", line 2652, in _postDOMValidate
    self._validateAttributes()
  File "/home/aoidoh/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxb/binding/basis.py", line 2246, in _validateAttributes
    au.validate(self)
  File "/home/aoidoh/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxb/binding/content.py", line 251, in validate
    raise pyxb.MissingAttributeError(type(ctd_instance), self.__name, ctd_instance)
pyxb.exceptions_.MissingAttributeError: Instance of <class 'DB01048.drugbank_type'> lacks required attribute exported-on
```

Comment: Is unmarshalling the xml into a python object an option, instead of a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more pythonic method could be to use the PyXB package to generate a python object unmarshalled from the xml file.

- Install PyXB package

`pip install PyXB`

- Create python module from downloaded xsd. Will create DB01048.py

`pyxbgen -m DB01048 -u drugbank-plus.xsd --no-validate-changes`

- Use the generated module as

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function
  import DB01048

  xml = open('DB01048.xml').read()
  d_01048 = DB01048.CreateFromDocument(xml)

  print(d_01048.drug[0].state)
  print(d_01048.drug[0].name)
  print(d_01048.drug[0].general_references.articles.article[0].pubmed_id)
  ```

`solid
 Abacavir
 17356469`

If a MissingAttribute error appears related to some `exported-on` attribute, add the following lines before the first Class on DB01048.py

`pyxb.RequireValidWhenParsing(True)
pyxb.RequireValidWhenParsing(False)`

Comment: I really appreciate this. But is the drugbank-plus.xsd file freely available? When I go to the downloads folder of drugbank [here](https://www.drugbank.ca/releases/latest), there is only a drugbank.xsd file and not drugbank-plus.xsd file? When I have the (1) DB01048.py file, (2)  DB01048.xml and (3) drugbank.xsd file in the one directory and run the code above, I get an error, I've added the input and error to my above question to show you, I'm wondering if it's the result of a difference between drugbank and drugbank-plus?

Comment: Also just to mention, it may or may not be relevant, when I run `pyxbgen -m DB01048 -u drugbank.xsd --no-validate-changes`; I get a lot of warning such as `WARNING:pyxb.binding.generate:Element use {http://www.drugbank.ca}drug-type.{http://www.drugbank.ca}volume-of-distribution renamed to volume_of_distribution` ;not sure if it's important to mention (because from reading around e.g. [here](https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb/issues/60), it doesn't seem to cause other people issues.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed that is wrong with my original script is that for some reason it duplicates the data in the output dictionary, but maybe that's to do with a for loop or something.

Comment: The `drugbank-plus.xsd` is declared in the XML first tag, so it must be public for consumers to parse it. Regarding the warnings, seems to be caused by hyphens in element names, couldn't figure out how to avoid it yet. You could also observed an error related to `exported-on` attribute on some elements, to fix it you need to add a couple of lines to DB01048.py. Unfortunately don't have them at hand, will add to the answer later today.

Comment: Thanks; so [here](https://www.drugbank.ca/releases/latest); I seem to only be able to get drugbank.xsd; is this where you got your file from? Yes the warnings are fine, I've been checking around. If you could, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: hey, I got the url form the root tag of the xml (second URL in xsi:schemaLocation namespace declaration): `<drugbank xmlns="http://www.drugbank.ca" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank-plus.xsd" version="5.1">`. Open it in a browser or download with wget/curl.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it was invaluable.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to hear it helped.